# CSS to remove suggested replies in new Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, css

I am reluctantly transitioned to the new Gmail.  It's bigger and loads slower, but it appears I'm stuck with it.

My wishlist item at the moment is CSS that will block display of the suggested quick replies to email that appear at the bottom of messages.  I find that *intensely* annoying.  I've poked around in places like UserStyles, but haven't seen what I'm looking for.

Suggestions gratefully accepted

Answer (score 3):

Open Gmail's Settings screen (gear button → *Settings* → *General*).

Scroll down to *Smart Reply* and disable it:

> [image: Smart Reply screenshot]

While on the same page, you might also want to disable inline *Smart Compose* suggestions as well (the option is actually slightly above Smart Reply):

> [image: Smart Compose screenshot]

Don't forget to click **Save Settings** at the bottom.

---

If you like, the *actual* classic Gmail interface is available at https://mail.google.com/mail/h/ (or by clicking the "Load basic HTML" link in the loading screen).